# Postfix with DKIM on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, domain, dkim

I want to improve deliverability for my outgoing emails with DKIM.  I've gotten dkim-filter installed for postfix, using this tutorial
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM

It seems to be working, my /var/log/mail.log shows it starting:

```
Aug 10 18:34:13 mail dkim-filter[5284]: Sendmail DKIM Filter v2.8.2 starting (args: -x /etc/dkim-filter.conf -u dkim-filter -P /var/run/dkim-filter/dkim-filter.pid -p inet:8891@localhost)
```

However, no headers are being generated when I send email and I can't figure out why.

Here is my /etc/dkim-filter.conf
https://gist.github.com/6dc92c7efc29aa45991f

And here's what I added to the bottom of /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

P.S. I have the DNS entry setup for it as well at feedmailpro.com (may still be propagating), but I assume it isn't even being checked without the headers in outgoing emails.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out why.  It was because I was sending email with a from address different than my domain.  Once I changed the from address to an address to contact@feedmailpro.com, it started signing them.

This is obvious in hindsight since i guess that's what domain keys do, is sign the from domain.  For some reason I had assumed it was signing based on the return path or the mail server IP, and not the from address.

Since I'm building an ESP (email service provider) I need the ability to send email from lots of domains.  So my next challenge is to get it signing for all domains.

**Edit: Solution posted here**
[DKIM sign outgoing mail from any domain (with Postfix and Ubuntu)](https://serverfault.com/questions/52830/dkim-sign-outgoing-mail-from-any-domain-with-postfix-and-ubuntu/52844)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a postfix install with DKIM signature on multiple domains. I've found that it was easier to configure amavisd-new to do that signature than using dkim-filter. Anyway, I would have added amavisd-new to my email stack in order to do spam checking.