# Setting up DKIM for multiple domains on same host

Tags: email, dkim, domain

I have DKIM set up for one domain and it works properly. I am trying, though, to set it up for another domain name on the same machine. In short, I am sending registration and password recovery emails from one domain and everything else from the other domain. Both domains map to the same host.

Setting up domainkeys in this manner was no problem - adding another "DAEMON_OPTS=" line in /etc/default/dk-filter was the solution. This is not the case for DKIM, though, since it stores this information in a configuration file (/etc/dkim-filter.conf) that is formatted in a completely different manner.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this person's question and answer:

DKIM sign outgoing mail from any domain with postfix and ubuntu

[DKIM sign outgoing mail from any domain (with Postfix and Ubuntu)](https://serverfault.com/questions/52830/dkim-sign-outgoing-mail-from-any-domain-with-postfix-and-ubuntu)

You may also need to read this (especially if you're on Ubuntu)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM

You'll still need to poke around a bit to see what configurations are relevant to you, but hopefully this will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos/RHEL take a look at this http://www.topdog.za.net/postfix_dkim_milter

Answer (score 0):

The private key file used by DKIM is specified in /etc/dkim-filter.conf file, in the line beginning with 'KeyFile'. You can use this config file and  private key with multiple domains, just list all the domains on the line starting with 'Domain'