# DKIM-filter is signing mails with invalid DKIM signatures (v=1 instead of v=DKIM1 etc)

Tags: email, dkim

I followed the `dkim-filter` install instructions from Ubuntu's [community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM)

My `dkim-filter` is signing DKIM signatures with this

```
v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=my.domain.com;s=mail; t=1312301159;bh=*hashstring omitted*=;h=Subject:Message-Id:Date:From:To;b=*key omitted*
```

GMail and Hotmail both say the DKIM's invalid (bad format)
the [dkim checker](http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck) says version should be `v=DKIM1` and not `v=1`, `a` is not a defined field, `c` is not a defined field, `d` is not a defined field, and `mail` is not a valid service type, among a bunch of other stuff

Did I misconfigure something in `dkim-filter`?

---

Answer:

Turns out my registrar only allows 64 characters in the TXT entry boxes..man this sucks

Comment: Postfix can not do anything with DKIM. Therefore it delegates everything to dkim-filter. This is why I'm going to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got something wrong. The dkim-checker checks DKIM-DNS records, not DKIM signatures. Your signature looks pretty good (except the omitted values).

Comment: Oh. Maybe the DNS records haven't propagated yet? Can I check that?

Comment: Sure. `dig` for it.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but when I enter the DKIM TXT record, should it be "mail._domainkey.my.domain.com." with the period at the end, or without? The community help page shows it having a period at the end, but I don't understand why it's there, and I can't tell either way if it's not working because of the delay in propagation or of it's a problem somewhere else :(

Comment: It must work with the dot in the end and without the dot in the end. But to make sure you really lookup the right entry please add the dot in the end. It makes sure that you lookup a FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a close duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/52830/dkim-sign-outgoing-mail-from-any-domain-with-postfix-and-ubuntu) one. Follow the instructions there.