# Make postfix/opendkim sign mail from all domains

Tags: postfix, opendkim

So, at the moment I am signing mails from specific domains using opendkim and this works. But when I try to send mails from domains that opendkim does not know, they they are not signed.

What I want to do, is to make opendkim sign all emails going through postfix using a single domain, just like mailchimp etc is doing.

Example:
I am sending emails from myname@mydomain.com using mailchimp, and the signeture is something like the following:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=k1; 
  d=mail2.suw13.rsgsv.net;
  h=Subject:From:Reply-To:To:Date:Message-ID:
    List-ID:List-Unsubscribe:Sender:Content-Type:MIME-Version; 
  i=*****mydomain.com@mail2.suw13.rsgsv.net; 
  bh=4Rla76/wHV31ER3IZqXOuA09j3OG2SuFbfD5Jc7Kn94=;  
  b=17jmyvz05JfeNC+avqWJmtESF2A58LA/CievFVtQ0sqwo4FYKAP
    0Gfpjtc5LSG7tr9ntS5CziAgSOa+UyEjRP3AhZOOXDFoQMUG0gn
    tqxg/gP074Vi7Hy0XvFzAiJYZfAhijwvaroY45hjuX+RN3nQ0xT
    fhWem5mv3+VVYpwvUo=
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot achieve this at all, as DKIM has two parts to configure. opendkim is one side, the other side is to put the public keys for your domain into a DNS record. So a "catch all" configuration cannot work as opendkim does not which key to use for which domain or even if one of its keys is correct for the domain.

Comment: If you want to use some automation, you can try a tool like ansible to generate opendkim configurations and DNS zonefiles for your domains.

Comment: I see your point. But what am I missing? I received an email from and would like to do the same. Example: Company Support <support@company.com> via mail136-21.atl41.mandrillapp.com, and later: signed by: mail136-21.atl41.mandrillapp.com How do they achieve this?

Comment: @allo A “catchall” configuration can indeed sign with _your_ domain all Email, no matter where from. – If the receiver gives credit to signatures like that is a different topic. (The receiver can at least be sure, that it passed the signing mail server.)

Answer (score 1):

like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/52830/dkim-sign-outgoing-mail-from-any-domain-with-postfix-and-ubuntu)  the trick lies in the use of `SigningTable` and `KeyTable`:

/etc/opendkim.conf

```
...
SigningTable    refile:/etc/mail/dkim_signing_table
KeyTable        csl:keyname=example.com:selector:/etc/mail/selector.key
```

/etc/mail/dkim_signing_table

```
* keyname
```

So the `SigningTable` maps all domains to a key, and the `KeyTable` provides a domain/selector for the keyname.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the message isn't signed for your own domain, but for `d=mail2.suw13.rsgsv.net`, instead. MailChimp has that as their *default authentication*, but it [recommends](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-email-authentication/) using *Custom Domain Authentication* i.e. having an own DKIM authentication for every domain.

> It removes the default MailChimp authentication information ( ["via
>   mcsv.net" or "on behalf of mcsv.net"](https://mailchimp.com/help/my-campaign-from-name-shows-mcsvnet/)) that shows up next to your
>   campaign's From name in certain email clients.

For the same reason you shouldn't try to have a single domain for signing messages for all domains.

Comment: according the the sprit of the RFCs you should even try to sign each type of message in a domain with different signing domain.

Answer (score 0):

`opendkim` always decides “itself” if it signs or not (then it verifies). You can only manipulate it’s decision and convince it to sign with:

1. have key material available for the email in question
2. let the MTA send a predetermined key-value pair to `opendkim`

The following lines are the crucial elements to my “sign all” configuration:

### /etc/opendkim.conf

```
SigningTable csl:*=key1
KeyTable     csl:key1=example.org:selector:/etc/dkimkeys/key.private
MacroList    csl:{dkimsign}=yes,dkimsign=yes
Socket       local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Line 1: use “key1” for all domains
Line 2: In the DKIM-Signature header use “d=example.org; s=selector;” and use that private key for signing
Line 3: request `{dkimsign}` and `dkimsign` from the MTA and sign the email if any of them is set to `yes` (see Notes below)
Line 4: socket for communication with MTA
Line 1 and 2 fulfill the 1. from above, Line 3 is for 2. from above.

### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
milter_macro_defaults = dkimsign=yes
smtpd_milters = unix:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Line 1: set `dkimsign` attribte to `yes`
Line 2 and 3: socket to use to reach the filter app (same as for opendkim above, but relative to postfix chroot...)

Notes:

- opendkim’s surprises

  - option `Mode=s` does not force signing
  - option `LogWhy` does not log why
  - there is nothing on standard out/error even without `SysLog`
- neither `opendkim` nor `postfix` have proper
- something is buggy: opendkim needs to request `{dkimsign}` and `dkimsign` (or any other attribute, but with and without braces), otherwise it does not work; might also be the fault of `postfix`

Comment: Neither `opendkim` nor `postfix` have proper what?

Comment: @GrantGryczan I wish I would still know what I had in mind 2 years ago.